# How to disable a knockout generated dropdown option by default

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, dropdown-options, enable-disable

I am trying to disable a certain option of select generated from knockout on the checkout page. I tried what was mentioned on the knockout [documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) i.e. to call `optionsAfterRender`. But this gives error and I think magento provides AfterRender for this, but the function example provided on the official documentation does not work.

the following code does not work to my expectations i.e. to disable certain option.

```
setOptionsDisable: function (option, item) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {disable: item.disable}, item);
        },
```

Although I have also added `disable: ko.observable(true)` to the observable array  as key|value.

So, how do I disable the option once it's been rendered? I don't think it can be disabled while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a core option, or an option that's been added yourself to checkout via layout - it can be disabled via layout. See devdocs below:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable

You will have to find the node for the element in `checkout_index_index.xml` and mark it a disabled as per docs.

Comment: e.g. I am getting list of all coupons and creating a dropdown using knockout, but now I also want to disable the option of coupon that was used. in PHP I could achieve this by simple if condition. But how do I do this in ko in magento? by default its possible in knockout however, how to do it in magento?